# Manual per-glyph rendering with SDL_TTF

Tags: rendering, sdl2, fonts

I'm trying to create a font atlas with SDL_TTF. My idea was to create an `SDL_Surface` for every character using `TTF_RenderGlyph_Blended()` and use `TTF_GlyphMetrics()` to get glyph metrics so that I can position the surface relative to a baseline. I'm struggling with a correct positioning of a glyph. It looks like SDL_TTF creates a surface with height which is at least the height of the font and width which is at least advance of a glyph, so the surface is bigger than just the glyph. How do I extract glyph's rectangle from the created surface? How do I position the glyph correctly relative to the base line on the screen? I thought y position of the glyph it should be `baselineY - maxy` (where maxy is from `TTF_GlyphMetrics`), but that places glyph too high above the base line.

Comment: As far as I can tell from [this doc](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_38.html), the baseline is at the origin of the returned values, so the offset to the top of the glyph is just `-yMax`.

Comment: Judging by implementation, `TTF_RenderGlyph_*()` compute glyph dimentions in a [quite involved way](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/file/d56ce74ac2ad/SDL_ttf.c#l2584), not simply returning values provided by the freeType library. So far I ended up using the freeType library directly.